# why does my floating point converting to binary number does not work for some decimal values?

Tags: python, recursion, binary, global

Here is my python code to convert just decimals to binary numbers, it works for some easy numbers like 0.75, but when I give it some hard numbers like 0.876, the answer will become [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1] but the real binary should be 0.11100000010000011001. I just cannot figure out why, can someone help me?

```
bina = []
ori = 0.5
nextn = 0
def ftob(x):
   global ori
   global nextn
    if x == 0:
        return bina
    else:
        a = x/ori
        if a >= 1:
            bina.append(1)
            nextn = x - ori
            ori = ori/2
        else:
            bina.append(0)
            ori = ori/2
        return ftob(nextn)
print(ftob(0.876))
```

Comment: There is no exact representation of 0.876 in binary. Both your result and your expected result are approximations (`0.87600000000000000089` and `0.87600040435791015625`, respectively). Actually yours is a closer approximation.

Comment: @Selcuk How did you get those two? The first one looks wrong.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode I used an online calculator and verified it using another one. What do you mean by _looks wrong_? What is your result?

Comment: @Selcuk It *looks wrong* because it ends with a 9, that immediately rules it out as the exact value. I get [0.87600000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625](https://tio.run/##bY7PCoMwDMbvfYpcpK0UZ5ThDvNJxg4dWNbh2tL2sqfvqrI/oiGE5Msv5HOveLemPTmf0k3HAD1cUMCS9SZxT8E9ADcArvt/DNfb7eGvXgmRIQw@wjgYNlnmcO7h2BKdvWsTGaXVw2rDntKxEL2AGeICGk6cnwjNicqwGq2ch0VVn4bRoupqRaEApuAATVl@f@VI6Q0).

Comment: Yes, it goes on, but the point is `0.11100000010000011001` is not a better answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try to understand your advices, and now I know at least my code is not wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> Note that this is in the very nature of binary floating-point: this is
> not a bug in Python, and it is not a bug in your code either. You’ll
> see the same kind of thing in all languages that support your
> hardware’s floating-point arithmetic (although some languages may not
> display the difference by default, or in all output modes).

Floating-point numbers are represented in computer hardware as base 2 (binary) fractions. For example, the decimal fraction

```
0.125
```

has value `1/10 + 2/100 + 5/1000`, and in the same way the binary fraction

```
0.001
```

has value `0/2 + 0/4 + 1/8`. These two fractions have identical values, the only real difference being that the first is written in base 10 fractional notation, and the second in base 2.

Unfortunately, most decimal fractions cannot be represented exactly as binary fractions. A consequence is that, in general, the decimal floating-point numbers you enter are only approximated by the binary floating-point numbers actually stored in the machine.

Interestingly, there are many different decimal numbers that share the same nearest approximate binary fraction. For example, the numbers `0.1` and `0.10000000000000001` and `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625` are all approximated by `3602879701896397 / 2 ** 55`. Since all of these decimal values share the same approximation, any one of them could be displayed while still preserving the invariant `eval(repr(x)) == x`.

Historically, the Python prompt and built-in `repr()` function would choose the one with 17 significant digits, 0.10000000000000001. Starting with Python 3.1, Python (on most systems) is now able to choose the shortest of these and simply display 0.1.

information from: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: Thank you so much, I will take a look at the rounding thing in python. It is kind of hard to understand.